# How to convert SSRS report to .svc file using a scheduled job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssrs-2012

I am in a need of fetching data from SQL Server 2012, create a file (e.g. excel) and export the file to some shared location. How could I achieve this using SSRS? I have been suggested that I could convert SSRS report file to .svc file type using job schedule. Sounds bit peculiar to me. Could anyone suggest, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using **Subscriptions** (if you are not running SQL Server Express). Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156307.aspx

I think that's far the easiest solution - just a few clicks and you're done ;-)

Comment: CeOnSql, I am afraid I did not see file sharing subscription for SQL 2012. But with SQL 2014, SQL 2016, I believe this will be very useful feature. Thank you.

Comment: that works at least since 2008R2! http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/report-subscription-in-ssrs-2008-r2.html

Comment: finally we achieved this using data driven subscription in SSRS report. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

.svc is ms wcf extenstion, I wonder how can SSRS converted to svc. Or did they mean that call .svc and run a report?

Alternatively You can use Report Server Web Service. Have a look on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787(v=sql.120).aspx) article, which may help you

Comment: Thank you Pravin. I guess Report Server Web Service will be the best choice. :)

Comment: You are welcome @sangam, Let us know if you need any help.